# XmlWriter.WriteStartDocument() is not outputting the declaration to the file

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader, xmlwriter

Ok so I have a method which should read an XML documents and then wrap them all up in a bigger XML document.

```
<Elements>
    <Element>
    <Element>
</Elements>
```

the issue is that when using the code below the output file is missing the declaration

```
<?xml >
```

any reason why this is? I am hoping it is something stupid I am missing.

```
XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(outputFileName, xwsSettings);

xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();

xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Elements");

foreach (var item in items)
{
    xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(item.FullFilename);

    while (xmlReader.Read())
    {
        if(xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
        {
            xmlWriter.WriteRaw(xmlReader.ReadOuterXml());
            break;
  }
    }
}

xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument();

xmlWriter.Flush();
xmlWriter.Close();
xmlWriter = null;
```

Comment: What are the settings in `xwsSettings`?

Comment: yes thanks @Tim, what a complete idiot I am...

xwsSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;

I did previously deal with ConformanceLevel.Fragment which is why I guess I had omitted  the declaration...

what an idiot

Comment: try ` XmlWriter.Create(sw, new XmlWriterSettings { OmitXmlDeclaration = true });`

Comment: Happens to us all, especially if we've been staring at code for a long time :)

Comment: @Nilesh - OP wants to include the XML Declaration, not omit it.

Comment: @Nilesh no my problem is that I was have delcared OmitXmlDeclaration = true
but the behaviour I wanted was actually
OmitXmlDeclaration = false

Comment: My bad. I copied and pasted the code. forgot to change true to false Sorry about that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Tim had hightlighted to check I had my XmlWriterSettings incorrectly set

```
XmlWriterSettings xwsSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
xwsSettings.CheckCharacters = false;
xwsSettings.CloseOutput = true;
xwsSettings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document;
xwsSettings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
xwsSettings.Indent = false;
xwsSettings.NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.None;

xwsSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true; <---- should have been false;
```